# Integrals with the Delta Function: Do I have to integrate and put the integration limits into the function? Or $\int_1^5 f(x)\delta(x-3) \, dx=f(3)$?

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

I tried exercise a) from this page and got a different result
https://en.universaldenker.org/exercises/1359

$f(x)=2x^2-x+1$

$$\int_1^5 (2x^2-x+1)\delta(x-3) \, dx =  \int_{1}^5 f(3) \, dx = \int_{1}^5 2\cdot 3^2-3+1\, dx= \int_{1}^5 16\, dx= [16x]_{1}^5=16\cdot 5-16=64$$

The solution on the website is $f(3)=16$, I don't understand why?

Comment: The answer is $f(3)$, almost by definition of what Dirac’s Delta is. $\delta_a$ is an object which eats functions $f$ and outputs their value at the point $a$. In your case $a=3$. You DON’T integrate $f(3)$ over the interval.

Comment: Use the property $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) \delta(x-x_0) dx = f(x_0)$

Comment: In distribution, $f(x)\delta(x-x_0)=f(x_0)\delta(x-x_0)\ne f(x_0)$